# HTML Metatags, where (which pages) to put what

Tags: html, where-clause, meta-tags

I have a batch of keywords that describe my site and I would like to be used for metatags, search engine optimization.

I'm curious though which page(s), do I put it? Where I'm usually confused is, do I just put in in my index page or for each page? If it's each page, can i just use the exact same batch I used in index or do I edit it a bit (how)?

I've had previous experiences with small sites that they show up in the search results with the corresponding keywords, but what ends up featured is the contact us page, on other case the about page (obviously i want the main page). I used the exact same keywords on every page.

What's the best practice in dealing with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *best* practise would be to apply keywords to each page as they describe that very page. That way search engines are more likely to show the page in the search results as the query matches the page more and so users are more likely to actually find what they are looking for. SEO is not just about getting visitors, but about serving visitors what they want so that they may eventually do business with you, whatever that business is.

Does that help? Or are you looking more for a how-to than a what/why?

Comment: follow up question: what do I put on my index page so that it has the most priority compared to the other pages? (about, contact us, etc)